# cakephp match against order by doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, match, against

I am trying to **order** my pagination result. But it doesn't work.

```
$this->paginate = array(
                'limit' => 15,
                'fields' => array('*', "MATCH (headline, author, short_headline, subline, teaser, text) AGAINST ('$var') AS score"),
                'conditions' =>  "MATCH(headline, author, short_headline, subline, teaser, text) AGAINST('$var' IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
                'order' => array('score' => 'desc')
            );
```

The query looks like:

```
SELECT *, MATCH (`headline`, `author`, `short_headline`, `subline`, `teaser`, `text`) AGAINST ('herz tod') AS `score`, `Story`.`id` FROM `fates`.`stories` AS `Story` WHERE MATCH(headline, author, short_headline, subline, teaser, text) AGAINST('herz tod' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 15
```

**and order by score is gone!** What i am doing wrong? thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making score a virtualField before you try to paginate in order to use it to order your pagination.  (There may be other ways to get it to order by score, but I'm not aware of them.)

```
$this->Model->virtualFields['score'] = "MATCH (headline, author, short_headline, subline, teaser, text) AGAINST ('" . Sanitize::escape($var) . "')";
```

I'd like to also point out, just in case, that your code (and the code I posted above for that matter) is vulnerable to SQL injection, if you cannot assume `$var` to be trustworthy data, like if `$var` comes from user input.

Comment: Thank you Kai! This works fine. And yes, i will use this for a site search. You are right. I have to validate $var through the Model to prevent SQL injection.